# Xcode - using a segue identifier to query a parse.com database

Tags: xcode, menu, parse-platform, segue

I am new to Xcode (please be kind), I am developing an application for car sales using parse.com as a back-end. I found a great tutorial and modified it for my needs.

However, I would like to have a menu at the front end where the user could select the "series" of car they are interested in and from the segue between the menu and the table view controller use this to filter the parse.com query.

I have tried many approaches but none seem to work, could someone kindly help me out.

I have created 3 view controllers in my storyboard: menu -> tableViewController -> ViewController.

My current code is as bellow:

Car.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface Car : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *model;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *price;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *Photo1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *mileage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *year;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *series;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *BodyType;

@end
```

Car.m

```
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car

@synthesize model;
@synthesize price;
@synthesize Photo1;
@synthesize mileage;
@synthesize year;
@synthesize series;
@synthesize BodyType;

@end
```

MenuViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MenuViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)serieone:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)serietwo:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)seriethree:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)seriefour:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)seriefive:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)seriesix:(id)sender;

@end
```

MenuViewController.m

```
#import "Car.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "CarTableViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)serieone:(id)sender {
// self.series = @"1 Series"
// [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"serieOneSegue" sender:self];
}

- (IBAction)serietwo:(id)sender {
.
.
// Other series types repeated
.

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
// Car * CarTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
// CarTableViewController.series = self.series
}

    }
@end
```

CarTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Car.h"

@interface CarTableViewController : PFQueryTableViewController

@end
```

CarTableViewController.m

```
#import "CarTableViewController.h"
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"
#import "Car.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface CarTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation CarTableViewController {

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"Car";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"Model";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 10;
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
{

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];

// need to replace the equal to as a variable which is provided from the button selector in MenuViewController

//[query whereKey:@"Series" equalTo:result];

query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
/*    if ([self.objects count] == 0) {

 }*/

//    [query orderByAscending:@"name"];

return query;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"CarCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell
PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"Photo1"];
PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
[thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

UILabel *modelLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
modelLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Model"];

UILabel *priceLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
priceLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Price"];

UILabel *mileageLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
mileageLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Mileage"];

UILabel *yearLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:104];
yearLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Year"];

UILabel *seriesLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:105];
seriesLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Series"];

UILabel *bodytypeLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:106];
bodytypeLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"BodyType"];

return cell;
}

- (void) objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error
{
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showCarDetail"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    CarDetailViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
    car.model = [object objectForKey:@"Model"];
    car.photo1 = [object objectForKey:@"Photo1"];
    car.price = [object objectForKey:@"Price"];
    car.series = [object objectForKey:@"Series"];
    car.derivative = [object objectForKey:@"BodyType"];
    car.mileage = [object objectForKey:@"Mileage"];

    destViewController.car = car;

}

}

@end
```

CarDetailViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Car.h"

@interface CarDetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet PFImageView *mainPhoto;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *seriesLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *modelLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *deivativeLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mileageLabel;

@property (nonatomic, strong) Car *car;

@end
```

CarDetailViewController.m

```
#import "CarDetailViewController.h"

@interface CarDetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation CarDetailViewController

@synthesize mainPhoto;
@synthesize priceLabel;
@synthesize seriesLabel;
@synthesize modelLabel;
@synthesize deivativeLabel;

@synthesize car;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = car.model;
self.priceLabel.text = car.price;
self.seriesLabel.text = car.series;
self.modelLabel.text = car.model;
self.deivativeLabel.text = car.derivative;
self.mileageLabel.text = car.mileage;
self.mainPhoto.file = car.Photo1;

- (void) viewDidUnload
{
[self setMainPhoto:nil];

[self setPriceLabel:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:    (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


@end
```

Comment: I want to use the buttons in the Menu View Controller to filter the data via a segue in the CarTabelViewController. For example if serieone button is pressed only results with series one in the series field will be displayed from parse database

Comment: What works and what doesn't?

Comment: Filter using segue doesn't work. Right now all the information from my database is displayed